# GeoJSON to SymPy Geometry

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, geojson, sympy

Does anyone know if you can convert GeoJSON geometries to SymPy Geometries?
If so, what package does this?
If not, can anyone think of a really fast way of converting the GeoJSON features to and from sympy quickly?  Preferably no worse than linear time.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of a library that does this, but you could build something fairly simply that would do this.

Sample geoJson:

```
{ "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
      { "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [102.0, 0.5]},
        "properties": {"prop0": "value0"}
        },
      { "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "LineString",
          "coordinates": [
            [102.0, 0.0], [103.0, 1.0], [104.0, 0.0], [105.0, 1.0]
            ]
          },
        "properties": {
          "prop0": "value0",
          "prop1": 0.0
          }
        },
      { "type": "Feature",
         "geometry": {
           "type": "Polygon",
           "coordinates": [
             [ [100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0],
               [100.0, 1.0], [100.0, 0.0] ]
             ]
         },
         "properties": {
           "prop0": "value0",
           "prop1": {"this": "that"}
           }
         }
       ]
     }
```

SymPy Polygon:

```
from sympy import Point, Polygon, pi
>>> p1, p2, p3, p4, p5 = [(0, 0), (1, 0), (5, 1), (0, 1), (3, 0)]
>>> Polygon(p1, p2, p3, p4)
Polygon(Point2D(0, 0), Point2D(1, 0), Point2D(5, 1), Point2D(0, 1))
```

As you can see, the geoJson features[2].geometry.coordinates array is almost exactly the same as the sympy geometry format (array of arrays vs array of tuples).  In terms of linear time, you could loop through the geoJson grabbing the coordinates array and setting it as the sympy values.

Complexity will be dependent on what geometry types you want to support (points, linestring, polygon etc..) as you will need to match them with the correct sympy syntax, but overall this would be trivial.

Comment: Great example! I think the biggest  issue is how to deal with 'LineString' types because Line and Segment only accepts 2 pts for the classes.

Comment: Agreed, a line string is slightly more complex (not sure if sympy has that type).  But you could always just draw p1 to p2, p2 to p3, p3 to p4..etc.

Comment: hmm, maybe another library would be better in my case.

Comment: What sympy functionality do you need?  Most calculations you can do straight from the geoJson format.